# Is data normally distributed at the 5% significance level?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a statistics question I cant wrap my head around:

[image]

The data sure looks normally distributed as it follows a bell curve and the mean, median, mode could are relatively the same. I just don't know how to mathematically prove this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove the data follows normal distribution. You can only do it statistically:

1. You get $n$ sample from data.
2. Let the null hypothesis $H_0$ that those samples is from normal distribution with parameter $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (In your case, $\mu=10.00$ and $\sigma=0.1$)
3. Perform a hypothesis test (e.g. Shapiro-Wilk test if you want to test normality)
4. Reject $H_0$ if you got a p-value <0.05 (under your 5% significance level)

However, if the diameter is following normal distribution, you will get positive probability that the diameter is negative. I think it does not make sense and the engineer may want to use log-normal distribution instead.